# React.js - Cant display array object in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I cant display array object in map function. Could someone please tell me why ? When Im trying to display this object in the console I see it correctly.

```
class ProductsGrid extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() {
    return (<Table striped bordered condensed hover>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Url</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {this.props.products !== null ?
                JSON.parse(this.props.products).map((product, index) => {
                    <tr>
                        {console.log(product.IdProduct)}
                        <td>{product.IdProduct}</td>
                        <td>{product.Name}</td>
                        <td>{product.Description}</td>
                        <td>{product.UrlFriendlyName}</td>
                    </tr>
                }) : <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>}
        </tbody>
    </Table>);
}}
```

Comment: Does your map function need a return?

Comment: Ofcourse.. What a stupid mistake, sorry..I've spend on this like one hour.

Comment: I've made many of those mistakes in my decades of programming :-) I hope my answer helps the next person who does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map function needs a return statement.